# String from javascript to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, http

I'm trying to use a string that i got from java script in my C# function,I'm only showing the relevant functions:

```
        <select id="select1">
                        <option value="Name1" selected>Name1</option>
                        <option value="Name2">Name2</option>
        </select>



 function ExecuteAjax(Url, model, successFunction, errorFunction) {
        //AJAX
        return $.ajax({
            //url thet will recieve the post
            url: Url,
            type: "POST",
            //data type is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect
            dataType: "json",
            //contentType is the header sent to the server, specifying a particular format
            contentType: "application/json",
            //data that will be passed through ajax
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            //function that will handle the success calback
            success: function (r) {
                if (successFunction) {
                    successFunction(r);
                }
            },
            //function that will handle the error calback
            error: function (r) {
                if (errorFunction) {
                    errorFunction(r);
                }
            }
        });//END AJAX
    }

    function buildSomething(groupName) {
        simpleDialog.loading();
        return ExecuteAjax('@Url.Action("BuildSomething", "Page")',groupName, buildSucess, buildFailed)
}



    function InitializeTab2() {
                //Starting the loading window
                simpleDialog.loading();
                groupName = 'Name1'
                $.when(
                    buildSomething(groupName)
                ).done(function () {
                    simpleDialog.close();
                });
            };

     $('#select1').on('change', function () {

            simpleDialog.loading();
            var groupName =  this.value;

            $.when(
                buildSomething(groupName)
            ).done(function () {
                simpleDialog.close();
            });
        });
```

My c# function only has 1 string as parameter but its always getting null when the function is called.
c# function:

```
public void myFunc(String groupName){
     Console.Write(groupName);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Only complex parameters are deserialized from body if not specified otherwise. Try to send your parameter in url or add [FromBody] in front of your parameter in method signature.

Comment: Can you have a look in the dev tools and see what is being posted payload-wise? You may need to send a proper object (groupname:"foo"} as opposed to just a stringified "foo" for example.

Comment: the null you are getting is when you debug in C# or in your ajax success function?

Comment: The null is from the C# function

Comment: I think @StephenByrne is right - you are just sending through a string as the data property. While it is syntactically valid, what it will do is build a query string. For example, if your groupName === "foo", it would say `"/Page/BuildSomething?foo"`, so your C# function is not recognizing that as valid, so it does not assign it to the groupName parameter. You need to say `data: {groupName: JSON.stringify(model)}` or you can say `data: "groupName=" + JSON.stringify(model)` - either one is valid